# special characters are not saved

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping

I needed to create a script to automate some procedures
but I have a question
when I use the command in .ps1

```bash
New-Item -Path $env:userprofile\Desktop\Cloack -Name "test.json" -ItemType "file" -Value "{ \`"a\`":b, \`n \`"b\`":c, etc .}"
```

then everything is written to the variable as expected

```
{ "a": b,
 "b":c, etc .}
```

but file .bat do it:

```bash
powershell New-Item -Path $env:userprofile\Desktop\Cloack -Name "test.json" -ItemType "file" -Value "{ `"a`":b, `n `"b`":c, etc .}"
```

the result I get is

```
`a`: b, 
`b`:c
etc .
```

I would like the **characters `"` and `{`** to be entered correctly when executing a `.bat` file
just like in the script

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your expected output (which doesn't match the PowerShell command's when executed from inside PowerShell), you're looking for something like this:

```bash
:: From a batch file
powershell -c "New-Item -Path $env:userprofile\Desktop\Cloack -Name test.json -Value \"{ `\"a`\":b, `n `\"b`\":c, etc .}\""
```

- `-c` (`-Command`) is the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter that is targeted by default, but included here for conceptual clarity.
- The entire command is enclosed in `"..."`, for robustness, to prevent potentially unwanted up-front interpretation of parts of the command by `cmd.exe`
- Whether or not you use `"..."` overall, `"` characters that should be *passed through* to PowerShell, as part of the command to execute must be *escaped*, as `\"`; the PowerShell CLI assumes *unescaped* `"` to have syntactic function *on the command line only*, and therefore *removes* them.
- Therefore, the `` \"{ `\"a`\":b, `n `\"b`\":c, etc .}\" `` part inside `"..."` above is ultimately seen and evaluated as follows, which I assume is what you want:

  ```bash
  "{ `"a`":b, `n `"b`":c, etc .}"
  ```